# Privacy over Virtualbox bridged networking

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, privacy, wireless-bridge

I'm connected to Internet provided by my organisation. The network is firewalled for logging. My machine name (say, "MachineMe" is set by my organisation, and all my traffic can be traced to my machine.

Now, suppose, I create a guest virtual machine Windows 10 in Virtualbox with a machine name (say "MachineVM"), with a bridged adaptor connected to my Wireless adaptor of my host. I received a different IP for my guest Windows 10 in the same subnet.

Now, if I use Internet through my virtual machine, what will be the machine name my org. can see? Is it "MachineVM" or "MachineMe"? What will be the MAC address and IP address visible to my org? Is it either my VM's or host's?

In this case, what are all the data of "MachineMe" exposed to my organisation?

Comment: Run `tracert <ip>` or similar to resolve the IP to a name and have a look whatever name is returned. It should be the name that's visible to your corporation. As for the MAC it would be the MAC of your machines network card. If you got an IP from the normal DHCP server that would also be the IP visible to whoever is communicating with the VM.

Answer (score 0):

I won't go into details because it looks like you're trying to break company policies. Anyway your "privacy" objective is wishful thinking in any half competent company.

If you run a VM in bridged mode then the IP address and mac address of the VM will be seen when you access internet.

The machine name is not sent when you try to use internet. However the VM could try to register its name with the DNS server (if configured to do so) and the DNS server could accept (normally only for domain members on a company network).

Comment: So, none of the information of my host machine (`MachineME`) is shared?